# Determining Range of Current Node in Segment Tree

Tags: data-structures, trees, binary-trees, discrete-mathematics

I was attempting, though failing quite miserably, to find some method of of determining the range of some node $n$. By range I mean an interval $[l,r]$ over the base array that is reachable by the sub-tree rooted at $n$.

I'm sorry of using incorrect terminology; I am inexperienced in formality. If, due to this, my explanation above does not make sense, I will instead provide a example:

For the Segmented Tree based off of $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$, the root $n_1$ would have a range $[0,l-1] = [0,7]$ for $l$ as the length of the the base array.
The root's left leaf $n_1$, would then have a range $[0,\left\lfloor\frac{l-1}{2}\right\rfloor]=[0,3]$.

The motivation for this is having a recursive update function that requires only the interval to be updated and the current node: $update(l,r,n_i)$

Comment: You need your function to have three parameters exactly and not permitted to add new parameters? If so, why? Anyway, you can emulate passing parameters by pushing them on the global stack.

Comment: I was simply wondering if there existed some function to determine this. Rather that given the base size and node, the range could be determined. Obviously not a necessity, but something that would vastly simplify the program and may help my understanding of the data structure as a whole.